# HTML5 player full screen issue

Tags: html, youtube, fullscreen

I wrote below code.
But Youtube player's full screen button didn't work.

And it runs on Android WebView but I can not modify WebView.

So, I want to hide the button or remove the button.

What should I do?

```
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          /* height: '206', 
          width: '336',*/
          videoId: '<%= avLink  %>',
          playerVars: { 'controls':1, 'showinfo':0, 'rel':0},
          events: {
              'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      function playVideo() {
        player.playVideo();
      }

      function pauseVideo() {
        player.pauseVideo();
      }

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == '1') { 
            $("#clickArea").show();
    }else{
            $("#pauseButton").hide(100);
            $("#clickArea").hide();
    }
  }
```